# Using a CTE to update in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update, common-table-expression

For logistic reasons, I want to set a value in a CTE to use in an `UPDATE` statement. Here is a simplified version:

```sql
with vars as (select 5 as n from dual)
update test set data=data*vars.n, more=more*vars.n;
```

Of course, in real life, the CTE will calculate a value from another source, but this should make the point.

I have sample at https://dbfiddle.uk/tUJoX5uw .

I get the error

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Is it possible to use a CTE this way for an `UPDATE` statement?

I know about some other SO questions, but generally they either end up using `MERGE`, or say that you can’t update the CTE itself. I don’t want to update the CTE, just to use the results. This is a question about the `UPDATE` statement.

**Update**

I have accepted an answer below. Here is a simplified version of the solution:

```sql
UPDATE TEST t
SET (t.data, t.more) = (
    SELECT vars.n*t.data, vars.n*t.more FROM (
        SELECT 5 AS n FROM dual
    ) vars
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work:

```
UPDATE TEST t SET (t.data, t.more) = (
    WITH VARS(n) AS (
        select 5 FROM DUAL 
    )
    SELECT v.n * t.data, v.n * t.more
    FROM vars v
)
;

SQL Error: ORA-01767: UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery
```

But this works:

```
UPDATE TEST t SET (t.data, t.more) = (
    SELECT (select 5 from dual) * t.data, (select 5 from dual) * t.more
    FROM DUAL
)
;
```

Comment: OK, how about this. I forget about the CTE, and do this: `UPDATE TEST t SET (t.data, t.more) = (SELECT vars.n*t.data, vars.n*t.more FROM (SELECT 5 AS n FROM dual) vars);`. That way the data is still only calculated once. I never knew you could set multiple columns with that syntax.

Comment: Yes, sure and probably the optimizer does the same.

Comment: If you happy to add the variation above, I can accept the answer. Thanks for the break through.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH should be inside the SET

```
UPDATE test SET data = (
    WITH vars(n) AS (
        select 5 FROM DUAL 
    )
    SELECT v.n * t.data
    FROM vars v
)
;
```

Comment: To me that looks like a sub query: wouldn’t `update test set data=data*(select 5 as n from dual);` do the same?

Comment: I think my example was too trivial. I’ve updated it to show updating two columns with the same value.